# Sidekiq Delay Extension not producing an email for *some* jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I have a really standard Rails Mailer which I am using [Sidekiq's Delay Extension](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Delayed-Extensions). I am trying to send about 20,000 emails and most of them work fine, but about 6000 seem to not work at all.

In a Sidekiq job I loop through all the relevant clients and call the delay mailer on each one:

```rb
campaign
  .clients
  .find_each do |client|
    CampaignMailer
      .delay
      .step(campaign_id, step, client.email, client.first_name)
  end
```

`CampaignMailer#step` is very generic with no early return statement or anything obvious:

```rb
class CampaignMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def step(campaign_id, step_name, email, first_name)
    @campaign = Campaign.find(campaign_id)
    @events = @campaign.events.future
    ...
```

When the email is sent, it takes about **1.5 seconds** to produce the complex HTML and send via Postmark

```
11084:2021-08-09T19:49:18.490Z 24735 TID-or8r5gewb Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer(---- !ruby/class 'CampaignMailer'- :step- - 1  - reminder_to_book  - xxx@example.com  - Name) JID-a3492a0743895c58de2891f7 INFO: start
11087:2021-08-09T19:49:19.988Z 24735 TID-or8r5gewb Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer(---- !ruby/class 'CampaignMailer'- :step- - 1  - reminder_to_book  - xxx@example.com  - Name) JID-a3492a0743895c58de2891f7 INFO: done: 1.498 sec
```

However, this is another almost identical job (just email address and first name is different), which ran in **0.005 seconds** and didn't produce an email:

```
19247:2021-08-09T20:01:43.683Z 24735 TID-grkw8ptkj Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer(---- !ruby/class 'CampaignMailer'- :step- - 1  - reminder_to_book  - yyy@example.com  - Name) JID-72acbf511e6720dbec92d5bd INFO: start
19249:2021-08-09T20:01:43.688Z 24735 TID-grkw8ptkj Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer(---- !ruby/class 'CampaignMailer'- :step- - 1  - reminder_to_book  - yyy@example.com  - Name) JID-72acbf511e6720dbec92d5bd INFO: done: 0.005 sec
```

0.005 seconds isn't enough time to do anything, not even a database lookup. it appears that the job is dropped immediately after being picked up.

The email was sent successfully when I re-created that same job later.

The are running the "sidekiq-unique-jobs" extension, which is set to `lock: :until_expired, lock_ttl: 1.hour, on_conflict: :log`. I know that this isn't triggered because we would otherwise get a log statement like:

```
2021-08-10T21:57:06.150Z 30264 TID-oxw249we0 SidekiqUniqueJobs::Client::Middleware DIG-uniquejobs:65cfc40dcae273c14282c749d1846b71 INFO: skipping job with id (06443737f9c2306dc927a962) because unique_digest: (uniquejobs:65cfc40dcae273c14282c749d1846b71) already exists
```

Does anyone have any idea what it might be? Could it be Redis load, with 20,000+ jobs? Is it something inside the delay extension?

Comment: The logs show that the job is being retrieved from Redis with the right payload, and 20,000 jobs with that size payload isn't really that much load, so I don't think that's your issue. I would be curious if you have any before filters on your mailer that might cause it to bail out early -- perhaps a list of opt-outs? 5ms is enough time for a quick database lookup. Do you have other Sidekiq extensions enabled? You can also consider adding more logging inside `step` to help determine if the code is being executed or not.

Comment: Thanks @RobertNubel. The CampaignMailer is all standard, not before filters or anything.

Comment: The are running the "sidekiq-unique-jobs" extension, which is set to `lock: :until_expired, lock_ttl: 1.hour, on_conflict: :log`. I know that this isn't triggered because we would otherwise get a log statement like:
`
2021-08-10T21:57:06.150Z 30264 TID-oxw249we0 SidekiqUniqueJobs::Client::Middleware DIG-uniquejobs:65cfc40dcae273c14282c749d1846b71 INFO: skipping job with id (06443737f9c2306dc927a962) because unique_digest: (uniquejobs:65cfc40dcae273c14282c749d1846b71) already exists
`

Comment: What version of sidekiq-unique-jobs are you running? There have been recent fixes pushed to it that may be related... the author has suggested everyone try the new version 7. That gem is third-party so there could definitely be a bug that's affecting you.

Comment: As a general debugging suggestion, you could instrument or log every place in the callstack up to and including the mailer's `step` method being invoked. To get that list of places, use a debugger and inspect the backtrace from inside that method; many of the places will be in gems which means you'll have to monkey-patch them to add that logging in production (or deploy with a forked version of the gem). Very annoying, but since it sounds like local reproduction is impossible here, it's the only path I can think of to make guaranteed progress.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I had wondered about the unique jobs middleware. We are using quite an old version, `6.0.21`!!!! While scrolling through the changelog, I see https://github.com/mhenrixon/sidekiq-unique-jobs/issues/418 with the title "Jobs executing and immediately returning" which seems to be exactly my issue, so I'll see if I can upgrade with more logging in place

Comment: Oh, good find -- I think there's a 99.9% chance that's your problem ;)